# Bootstrap collapsable panel doesnt work when adding styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap collapsible panel set up to expand and collapse a search bar. This works fine with no styling but when styling is added, it has a mind of its own. It looks like the styling is getting In the way of the collapsing transition. Then it just stops working.

Here is the code with the styling attached to this. I want this to be clickable on an `a href` link.

```css
#search-dropdown-div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

#center form {
  position: relative;
}

#center form input[type="search"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 16px !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#center form input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #3A83F3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#center form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #0D5C9E;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Collapse Training</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="mag-search" data-toggle="collapse" href="#search-dropdown-div"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search</a>
    <div id="search-dropdown-div" class="collapse">
        <div id="center">
            <form role="search">
                <input class="fontAwesome" type="submit" value="Search &#xf084 " />
                <input class="fontAwesome" type="search" placeholder="&#xf002; Search our website..." />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I tested with your code, I think it's the `display: inline-block` of `#search-dropdown-div` that causes problem.

Can you tell me if it works if you remove this line ?

Comment: Yes, you're right it does work fine when I isolate the code into a separate HTML document but it doesn't work on my website. Its infuriating.

Comment: OK now it expands on my website but doesn't collapse back in again when toggled.

Comment: Right so I've isolated it down the browser compatibility. Hw would I make this work across all browsers?

Comment: Have you isolated what part of your code doesn't pass the browser compatibility ?

Comment: And can you tell me on which browsers you tested it and what were the differences ? (maybe edit your original post and add these new informations)